# Rowwise name of column where first non-zero value appears

Tags: r, dplyr, names

I've got a bunch of columns all starting with the prefix `wtp_` that occur in the midst of a wide dataframe (with several columns before and after the `wtp_` columns). Mini example:

```
df <- tribble(~id, ~complete, ~wtp_20,~wtp_40,~wtp_60,~wtp_80,~wtp_100, ~sex,
          1, 1,  0,0,1,1,1,  "F",
          2, 0,  0,0,0,1,1,  "F",
          3, 0,  0,0,0,0,1,  "M",
          4, 1,  1,1,1,1,1,  "M",
          5, 1,  0,0,0,0,0,  "M",
          6, 0,  0,1,1,1,1,  "F"); df
```

What I'm looking for: I need to create a new variable (`min_wtp`) that returns the name of the column the *first time* that one of the `wtp_` columns switches from 0 to 1. In other words, I need a solution to create the following:

```
df_needed <- tribble(~id, ~complete, ~wtp_20,~wtp_40,~wtp_60,~wtp_80,~wtp_100, ~sex, ~min_wtp,
          1, 1,  0,0,1,1,1,  "F", "wtp_60",
          2, 0,  0,0,0,1,1,  "F", "wtp_80",
          3, 0,  0,0,0,0,1,  "M", "wtp_100",
          4, 1,  1,1,1,1,1,  "M", "wtp_20",
          5, 1,  0,0,0,0,0,  "M", "NA",
          6, 0,  0,1,1,1,1,  "F", "wtp_40"); df_needed
```

Please note the following complications:

-Some people (like id==5) never change to 1 while others (like id==4) are 1 all along.
-There are some irrelevant columns occurring before the `wtp_` columns that have 0s and 1s in them which should be ignored in the construction of `min_wtp`.
-There are way more columns (including `wtp_` columns) than the minimal example I included above.

I've tried playing with `which` and `colnames` functions in combination with `select(starts_with("wtp_"))` but have been unsuccessful.

If anyone has a dplyr solution, that would be preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `apply` to get, for each row, the number of first column that satisfies your conditions. Then we use that number as the index to get the column name.

```
df$min_wtp = apply(df[ , grepl("wtp", names(df))], 1, function(x) {
  names(x)[min(which(x > 0))]
  })

df
```

> ```
>      id complete wtp_20 wtp_40 wtp_60 wtp_80 wtp_100 sex   min_wtp
>   <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl> <chr> <chr>  
> 1     1        1      0      0      1      1       1 F     wtp_60 
> 2     2        0      0      0      0      1       1 F     wtp_80 
> 3     3        0      0      0      0      0       1 M     wtp_100
> 4     4        1      1      1      1      1       1 M     wtp_20 
> 5     5        1      0      0      0      0       0 M     NA     
> 6     6        0      0      1      1      1       1 F     wtp_40
> ```

Answer (score 2):

It would be much easier if you get the data in long format :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('wtp')) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(min_wtp = name[which(value == 1 & 
                           lag(value, default = 0) == 0)[1]]) %>%
  left_join(df, by = 'id')

# A tibble: 6 x 9
#     id min_wtp complete wtp_20 wtp_40 wtp_60 wtp_80 wtp_100 sex  
#  <dbl> <chr>      <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>
#1     1 wtp_60         1      0      0      1      1       1 F    
#2     2 wtp_80         0      0      0      0      1       1 F    
#3     3 wtp_100        0      0      0      0      0       1 M    
#4     4 wtp_20         1      1      1      1      1       1 M    
#5     5 NA             1      0      0      0      0       0 M    
#6     6 wtp_40         0      0      1      1      1       1 F
```

---

Without reshaping the data you can use `rowwise` with `c_across` :

```
apply_fun <- function(x) {
    which(x == 1 & lag(x, default = 0) == 0)[1]
}

cols <- grep('^wtp', names(df), value = TRUE)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(min_wtp = cols[apply_fun(c_across(cols))])
```

Comment: @thiagoveloso You do already have couple of answers and an accepted answer there. don't they work?

Answer (score 1):

If it never goes backwards from 1 to 0, then you can find the change point very quickly with some basic sums:

```
sw  <- startsWith(names(df), "wtp_")
names(df[sw])[sum(sw) - rowSums(df[sw]) + 1]
#[1] "wtp_60"  "wtp_80"  "wtp_100" "wtp_20"  NA        "wtp_40"
```